# How do you interact with a form when in a BackgroundWorker class 'completed' function?

Tags: vb.net, forms, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker that is used to carry a time consuming process while a form is shown. The form and the BackgroundWorker are in separate classes, and when the BackgroundWorker has finished what it has to do, I need to carry out some basic actions on the form.

However, the below does not work and produces the warning `Reference to non-shared member requires an object reference`.

```
Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

    mainForm.btnCancel.Enabled = False
    mainForm.btnFinish.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

I researched the warning and it suggested that I had to ensure the object `mainForm` was declared, which for this scenario seems odd from the get go. Regardless, I changed my code to this, and the warning disappeared, but as suspected, it doesn't work. It seems that a new instance of the form would be referenced, which is not what I require.

```
Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim objForm As New mainForm
    objForm.btnCancel.Enabled = False
    objForm.btnFinish.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me how I can interact with a form from a BackgroundWorker? Thanks.

Comment: You need a reference to the actual mainForm object that the user is looking at.  Pretty basic object-oriented programming requirement, always hard to cover the very basics in a SO answer.  Drop the BGW on the mainForm instead, then it is simply Me.btnCancel.Enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you need to declare *a new* `mainForm` object.  The problem is that you need a reference to *the right* `mainForm` object.  Since it is possible to create any number of `mainForm` objects, you need a reference to the particular `mainForm` object that you want to modify.  Remember, `mainForm` is the class (a type of object).  It is not, itself, an object.

The simplest way fix this would be to give a reference to the `mainForm` object to the class that is performing the work, like this:

```
Public Class MyBusiness
    Public Property TheMainForm As mainForm

    ' ...

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        TheMainForm.btnCancel.Enabled = False
        TheMainForm.btnFinish.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, before starting the work, you need to make sure you set the `TheMainForm` property.  For instance, something like this:

```
Dim business As New MyBusiness
business.TheMainForm = Me
business.DoWork()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for both the clear explanation and the example.